# Estilos para hijos de diferentes tablas

Tags: css

Tengo una tabla General, la cual le aplico los estilos de la siguiente manera:

```
#tableGral {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1300px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 60%;
}

table#tableGral td
{
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

El detalle que tengo, es que en algunas celdas de la tabla principal o general, tengo otras tablas. Lo que deseo es que estas tablas hijas no contengan bordes. He intentado de varias maneras, pero me sigue tomando el borde de la tabla principal:

```
.tableHija {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

table.tableHija td {
    margin-right: 7px;
    font-size: 9px;
    border: none;
}
```

Un ejemplo completo:

```css
#tableGral {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 80%;
}

table#tableGral td {
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.tableHija {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

table.tableHija td {
    margin-right: 7px;
    font-size: 9px;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<table id="tableGral">
 <tr>
   <td>Columna 1</td>
   <td><table class="tableHija">
     <tr>
       <td>Columna 1 de la tabla hija</td>
       <td>Columna 1 de la tabla hija</td>
     </tr>
   </table></td>
   <td>Columna 3</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Creo que no es buna idea tener tablas dentro de tablas, pero si agregas tu HTML quizas podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Gracias, lo resolvi con JQuery

Comment: @PolloKulos si lo resolviste, te aconsejo que publiques una respuesta mostrando lo que hiciste.

Comment: Agregue lo siguiente: $('.NoBorder').css('border', 'none'); donde, 'NoBorder es el nombre de la clase que le puse al td'

Comment: para eso no necesitas jQuery, solo estás aplicando una clase, ponlo en la hoja de estilos

Comment: El problema es cómo defines el estilo para `table#tableGral td`. Debería ser `table#tableGral>tbody>tr>td`.

Comment: ¿Ha ocurrido algo para que decidieras cambiar la respuesta correcta? Con su respuesta ese estilo se aplicaría a los `<td>` de otras subtablas de ella, si las hubiera. Ya puestos te apunto que hay un selector más corto para la respuesta que has marcado como correcta: `#tableGral .tableHija td {}`. No se necesita especificar etiquetas intermedias (el primer `<td>`) ni las del `id` ni `class`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes un problema de [especificidad](http://w3.unpocodetodo.info/css3/cascada.php). Para dar estilo a la tabla general utilizas un id `#tableGral`, mientras que para dar estilo a la tabla hija utilizas como selector una clase: `table.tableHija`. De esta manera los estilos de la `#tableGral` prevalecen.

Para solucionar tu problema puedes utilizar este selector: `table#tableGral td table.tableHija td {}`en lugar de `table.tableHija td {}`

```css
#tableGral {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 80%;
}

table#tableGral td {
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.tableHija {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

table#tableGral td table.tableHija td {
    margin-right: 7px;
    font-size: 9px;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<table id="tableGral">
 <tr>
   <td>Columna 1</td>
   <td><table class="tableHija">
     <tr>
       <td>Columna 1 de la tabla hija</td>
       <td>Columna 1 de la tabla hija</td>
     </tr>
   </table></td>
   <td>Columna 3</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

### Descripción del problema:

Debes indicar con precisión la jerarquía a la que quieres aplicar el estilo `table#tableGral td` ya que tal y como está se aplicará a cualquier elemento `<td>` que sea descendiente de `table#tableGral`, sea cual sea el nivel de descendencia (tabla, sub tabla, sub sub tabla, etc) debido a tiene mayor prioridad este selector al que usaste en `table.tableHija td` por tener una menor [especificidad](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Especificidad).

### Uso del selector de [hijo (descendiente directo `>`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator):

Indicando `table#tableGral > tbody > tr > td` se aplicará únicamente a los elementos que sigan estrictamente ese orden de descendencia. Hay que tener en cuenta que, aunque no tengas un `<tbody>`, debes indicarlo explícitamente en el selector de clase.

```js
var obtenerSelector = (elemento) => {
  var etiqueta = elemento.tagName.toLowerCase();
  if (etiqueta == "html") {
    return "html";
  }
  if (elemento.id != '') {
    etiqueta += '#' + elemento.id;
  } else if (elemento.className) {
    etiqueta += '.'
      + elemento.className.replace(/\s+/g, '.');
  }
  return obtenerSelector(elemento.parentNode)
    + " > " + etiqueta;
}
/* Mostramos la ruta al elemento por consola */
console.log(
  obtenerSelector(
    document.getElementById('ejemplo')
  )
);
```

```css
#tableGral {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 80%;
}

/* Especificamos la descendencia correctamente */
table#tableGral > tbody > tr > td {
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.tableHija {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

/* Aquí también deberíamos hacerlo */
table.tableHija > tbody > tr > td {
    margin-right: 7px;
    font-size: 9px;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<table id="tableGral">
 <tr>
   <td>Columna 1</td>
   <td><table class="tableHija">
     <tr>
       <td>Columna 1 de la tabla hija</td>
       <td id="ejemplo">Columna 2 de la tabla hija</td>
     </tr>
   </table></td>
   <td>Columna 3</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

El código javascript que he agregado te muestra el selector o ruta al elemento `<td>` de la subtabla, para que veas cómo existen elementos `<tbody>` que se han creado implícitamente:

```
html > body > table#tableGral > tbody > tr > td
  > table.tableHija > tbody > tr > td#ejemplo
```

---

### Uso de [excepción (`!important`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Especificidad#La_excepci%C3%B3n_!important):

De la documentación:

> Cuando se emplea `important` en una declaración de estilo, esta declaración sobrescribe a cualquier otra. Aunque técnicamente `!important`  no tiene nada que ver con especificidad, interactúa directamente con ésta. Sin embargo, **el uso de `!important` es una mala práctica** y debería evitarse porque hace que el código sea más difícil de depurar al romper la cascada (artículo en inglés) natural de las hojas de estilo.

Un ejemplo del uso de `!important` se muestra a continuación:

```css
#tableGral {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 80%;
}

table#tableGral  td {
    border: 1px solid lightgrey ;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.tableHija {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

table.tableHija td {
    margin-right: 7px;
    font-size: 9px;
    /* Aquí indicamos que debe prevalecer por encima de otros */
    border: 0px none !important;
}
```

```html
<table id="tableGral">
 <tr>
   <td>Columna 1</td>
   <td><table class="tableHija">
     <tr>
       <td>Columna 1 de la tabla hija</td>
       <td id="ejemplo">Columna 2 de la tabla hija</td>
     </tr>
   </table></td>
   <td>Columna 3</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Pero sólo se debería usar `!important` como último recurso, lo ideal es ser más conciso al establecer los estilos.